# SVG Animate 'beginElement()' not working in Windows Store App?

Tags: visual-studio, svg, winjs, svg-animate

I'm developing in Visual Studio 2013, with a WinJS HTML project, a windows store app. I get my animate object - `animEl = document.querySelector('animate')` - and call `beginElement()` on it, and I get an error. Looks like this method isn't available.

Is there an alternative?

Comment: what renderer are you targetting, MS renderers have never supported SMIL.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not sure how to answer that question. It's for Windows Store apps, primarily for Windows 10 devices but hopefully also compatible with Windows 8.1 devices. I have SVG graphics that work just fine, only the Animate element doesn't work.

Comment: Because those devices do not support SMIL animation. I.e. this [entire chapter of the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html) they do mostly implement the rest of the SVG specification.